# How font works in Unicode

Tags: php, unicode, fonts

I copied some chinese font and pasted in Sublime editor:

```
<?php
echo "木 mù";
?>
```

Now next I run it on Google browser `test.php`, it displays:

> æœ¨ mÃ¹

So here you can see the characters that I'm using in echo and the character that browser is displaying are different.
So my question is that: is it browser that does not support the font or is it PHP who does not understand it and displaying different result?

I need to `declare('any character-set')` in PHP file?

Comment: The browser understands the font, since me and you are both seeing it in the question. The problem is that PHP didn't set the encoding for the character it is inputting, so it doesn't knows how to properly display the character.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UTF-8 all the way through](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Comment: So what is the solution ?

Comment: The solution is to set headers with the proper encoding.

Comment: [ UTF-8 all the way through](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through) is so advance i can not understand this link.

Comment: Do you have following meta tag set in HTML? `<meta charset="utf-8">`

Comment: @PhiterFernandes what proper encoding should be there? PHP take by default utf-8.

Comment: @Thomas Orlita thanks its work.  but now i come to another point. if php take by default utf-8 character encoding then what is the use of <meta charset="utf-8"> . i think it need to work without <meta charset="utf-8">

Comment: Then set header before any output: `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### 1. Set following meta tag in HTML

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

[Documentation](https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-html-encoding-declarations).

### 2. Set header via PHP

Use following code before any output to set header to `utf-8` charset.

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

[PHP `header()` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php).